# Selenium headless mode few tests failing with NoSuchElementException using AjaxElementLocatorFactory

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, ajax-element-locator-factory

I have tests that passing by if i run it none headless and if headless mode are on which is running my tests under the boot then some tests are failing with an exception that element cannot be located. What to do in such scenarios

Also does it matter how big is a window size at all? currently i have the following, but i guess if they passing wish such window size none headless why would some fail headless

```
@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    driver = new ChromeDriver(new ChromeOptions()
            .addArguments("start-maximized")
            .addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking")
            .addArguments("--headless"));
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    loginToEnvironment();
}
```

In headless mode some element is not located

Elements initialisation done by PageFactory.init

```
public class BasePage {

    public WebDriver driver;
    protected Wait wait;

    public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
        initializePage(driver);
        this.wait = new Wait(driver);
    }

    final protected void initializePage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 20), this);
    }
}
```

[image]

SignUp test

```
@Test
    public void shouldSignUpSuccessfully() {
        signUpModal.signUp((SignUp) credentials)
                .getCountryModalInstance()
                .chooseCountry(((SignUp) credentials).getCountry())
                .clickOnSaveButton();
        assertTrue(homePage.getMyAccountName().getText().isEmpty());
    }
```

Stack track trace:

```
Timed out after 20 seconds. Unable to locate the element
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Timed out after 20 seconds. Unable to locate the element
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.AjaxElementLocator.findElement(AjaxElementLocator.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.getText(Unknown Source)
    at com.opngo.nowos.selenium.SignUpServiceTest.shouldSignUpSuccessfully(SignUpServiceTest.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:628)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:117)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:184)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:180)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:127)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService$ExclusiveTask.compute(ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:171)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:115)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService$ExclusiveTask.compute(ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:171)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:115)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService$ExclusiveTask.compute(ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:171)
    at java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:189)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:175)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".user-name"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=95.0.4638.69)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'MacBook-Pro-3.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:869:afaa:89ee:2f42%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.7', java.version: '1.8.0_302'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 95.0.4638.69, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 95.0.4638.54 (d31a821ec901f..., userDataDir: /var/folders/fy/4f9mrb0n1fq...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:62396}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 968cb69072e7bbe6a92b2822d8ad26ee
*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=.user-name}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:420)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElement(By.java:431)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.AjaxElementLocator.access$001(AjaxElementLocator.java:39)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.AjaxElementLocator$SlowLoadingElement.isLoaded(AjaxElementLocator.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.SlowLoadableComponent.get(SlowLoadableComponent.java:72)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.AjaxElementLocator.findElement(AjaxElementLocator.java:95)
    ... 48 more
```

Comment: Also use this args `options.add_argument("--start-maximized")`

Comment: What does the error says?

Comment: @cruisepandey hey man sadly it did not work and element still not intractable in headless

Comment: @DebanjanB element is not intractable in headless but it is on none headless

Comment: Update the question with the error stacktrace

Comment: Now you presenting `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Timed out after 20 seconds. Unable to locate the element` error. This is definitely not what you mentioned before `In headless mode some element is not intractable` ...

Comment: @Prophet you right, editing now sorry guys

Comment: How about the locator and the relevant HTML?

Comment: @DebanjanB @FindBy(css = ".user-name")
    private WebElement myAccountName;

Comment: @DebanjanB if you have sometime in chat i would be really thankful cheers

Comment: @Prozorov : You should add `--`, that is missing. Also it says, `Unable to locate the element`. Please see below, that may help you.

Answer (score 0):

for this css selector :

```
.user-name
```

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

css that you should check :

```
.user-name
```

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `css` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

If we have 1/1 matching node, Please make sure that :

1. This web element is not under an iframe.
2. This web element is not under a shadow root.
3. You should not be on the new tab/windows launched by selenium.

If it falls under any category mentioned above, You would have to handle that particular scenario.

Comment: Hey man i appreciate your time and contribution,  i have added a screenshot and test of mine above.

Comment: You can check `//div[@class='icon-profile-container']//child::span[@class='user-name']` xpath, does it show 1/1 matching node ? Please refer how to check section above.

Comment: Hey it locates //div[@class='icon-profile-container'] this way but if adding a child in a string it does not...

Comment: then that's the issue.. how many nodes for `//div[@class='icon-profile-container']//child::span[@class='user-name']` ? you would see something like 1/2 or 1/3 or something like that

Comment: do you my if i message you in chat?

Comment: so it wasnt a child of icon-profile its

//div[@class='header-menu-name']//child::span[@class='user-name']

Comment: i have specified xpath and it worked but really xpath is not the way as i have read it mostly is better to use css

this worked but i dont like it

//body/div[@id='__next']/div[1]/div[1]/nav[1]/div[1]/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]

Comment: css is better when it comes to performance, for this particular instance you may use CSS. Having said that, I would never recommend you to use the XPath `//body/div[@id='__next']/div[1]/div[1]/nav[1]/div[1]/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1] `, instead you could try to use some relative xpath.

Comment: Also, I saw your comment on another answer, Just letting you know it really does not matter if you are using implicit wait, that is just for findElement. I would suggest to use explicit wait.

Comment: @cruisepandey This comment _it really does not matter if you are using implicit wait_ is totally wrong and misleading. Check the documentation.

Comment: You should read the documentation carefully, there's nothing called implicit wait anymore.

Answer (score 0):

### AjaxElementLocatorFactory

[*AjaxElementLocatorFactory*](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/page-factory-pattern-in-selenium-webdriver) is a lazy load concept in Page Factory pattern to identify WebElements only when they are used in any operation i.e. a timeOut for a WebElement can be assigned to the Object page class with the help of AjaxElementLocatorFactory.

So ideally you need to remove the *implicitlyWait* as:

> [Warning](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#implicit-wait): Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause
> unpredictable wait times. For example, setting an implicit wait of 10
> seconds and an explicit wait of 15 seconds could cause a timeout to
> occur after 20 seconds.

---

*`NoSuchElementException`* indicates element wasn't located.

To locate the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  div.header-menu-item > div.header-menu-name span.user-name
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  //div[@class='header-menu-item']/div[@class='header-menu-item']//span[@class='user-name']
  ```

Comment: Hey thank you for your time, so if i have lazy load concept there i do not require implicitlyWait in my settings?

Comment: Ideally, you shouldn't, I've linked the documentation for your reference.